# Injecting Object into @Repository loaded with component-scan - No Autowired

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, repository

I have the following Dao class defined:

```
@Repository
public class MyDao {

  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  private String myString;

  @Autowired 
  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }
```

I'm using component scanning over the package where MyDao is defined so I do not have a bean definition for MyDao in my Spring configuration file. Is there a way to inject a String into myString without using autowiring? What are my alternatives for this?

Answer (score 2):

Spring comes with the @Value annotation that you can use to inject a string.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html

http://chrislovecnm.com/2010/03/08/spring-3-java-based-configuration-with-value/

There is also a configuration framework called [Constretto](https://github.com/constretto/constretto-core) that allows nested configurations (like json) to be injected.

Comment: Nice! What if I have a complex Object instead of a String though? Is there a Spring based trick to do that?

Comment: You can inject more complex object using Constretto or plain spring: http://www.bullraider.com/java/spring3/tutorials/spring-ioc-tutorials/injecting-complex-java-types